# react-native run-android command terminates by leaving a message in android Device

Tags: react-navigation

[react-native run-android command terminates by leaving a message in android simulator. The message is as follows:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU7OS.jpg)
The development server returned response erre code: 500

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It says you are missing a dependency. Install it with these commands:

```
npm install @react-navigation/native

cd ios && pod install && cd ..
```

Add the following in top your index.js

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

reference: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/